# Error when extending interface, type (of interface property) has no properties in common with type (of interface)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend an interface in TypeScript, but I'm getting a confusing error. It complains that the type of one of the properties of my interface has no properties in common with the interface itself.

`Error: /path/to/file.ts(123,33): semantic error TS2559: Type 'LogObj' has no properties in common with type 'EngagementData'.`

The interface I'm trying to extend:

```
export interface EngagementData {
    logs?: LogObj[] | LogObj,
    progress?: [] | number | ProgressObj,
    state?: {[key: string]: any}
}

export interface LogObj {
    action: string,
    action_mod_1?: string,
    action_mod_2?: string,
    timestamp?: number,
    description?: string
}

export interface ProgressObj {
    value?: number,
    label?: string,
    weight?: number,
    description?: string
}
```

I'm trying to extend it in a separate file, so at the top of the file where I'm extending it, I have an import:

```
import * as engagement from "../myFile";
```

And at the bottom of the file I extend it:

```
interface engagementData extends engagement.EngagementData {
    logs?: engagement.LogObj[];
}
```

Again, I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error. It seems like TypeScript is trying to match `LogObj` directly with `EngagementData`, instead of treating it as one of its properties.

I'm using TypeScript version 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoul write your `import` statement in other way:

```js
/**
 * Try to change your import 
 */
import {EngagementData, LogObj } from "../myFile";

interface NewEengagementData extends EngagementData {
    logs?: LogObj[];
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

My issue was, I had a function in the same file where I had defined my initial types:

```
export function postMessage(eventData: EngagementData) {
    window.parent.postMessage(eventData, "*");
}
```

And I was trying to use that function with the extended type in my other file.

By removing the type requirement on the `postMessage` function I was able to compile without any errors.